# The Java ternary operator and method overloading

Tags: java, overloading, return-type, conditional-operator, system.out

I've just recently learned that in Java, a ternary operator can return different types, and

```
int x = 6;
System.out.println( (x==6) ? true : "false" );
```

is valid Java code that prints "true".
However, when I try to make my own test method that accepts the output of this ternary statement, Java gives me an error.  Here's my code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 6;
        method( (x==6) ? true : "false" );
    }
    public static void method(boolean x) {
        System.out.println("int");
    }
    public static void method(String x) {
        System.out.println("String");
    }

}
```

and I get a compile-time error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean
```

Why does this work for the `println()` method, but not my own overloaded method? Also, when I switch the order of the methods, putting `method(String)` before `method(boolean)`, Java gives me a slightly different error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to String
```

Again, what causes this? Even though both cases lead to errors, why does different declaration order of methods lead to different errors from the compiler?

Comment: Try making an overload that takes `Object`

Comment: Why do you think you're using the `println(String)` version? `boolean` has no relation to `String`, thus it doesn't get converted to it automatically.

Comment: @Tom I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.  I didn't assume it was calling `println(String)`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard That works. Why does that work?